# Firestore - security rules: are multiple reads in OR connection and will evaluate "lazily"?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So my question is about a use case, when my rules looks like this:

```
match /collection/{docID} {
    allow read,write,update : if isSomethingTrue();
    allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && isOnotherFunctionWithGETInside();
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;

}
```

Am I right if I can translate my read rules as:

```
allow read: isSomethingTrue() || (request.auth.uid != null && isOnotherFunctionWithGETInside())
```

and if yes, won't the second part execute if the isSomething() returns true? So will it evaluate in lazy mode?

This is an important question for me, because there can be a big difference in the bill (server read operations), if I only swap the sequence of the two allow read lines (because of the get() function in the second read rule).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is called "short circuiting" in programming languages.  And yes, security rules will short circuit logical ORs in order to avoid evaluating the rest of the expression.  This is covered in the [API documentation for booleans](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Boolean) in security rules.

Comment: Okey awesome. I know about this ofc, but I leaned these things in Hungarian language, and there they called lazy. Thats all, thx for the clear up.